# C# Object type conversion to byte[], send over TCP and converting back to double

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, labview

I'm fairly new to C# programming and usually deal with PLC programming and HMI/SCADA systems development. The last one involves only a bit od C/VBS scripting.

Recently, in one of my projects I upgraded/migrated a SCADA systems initially developed in LabVIEW to the Siemens WinCC application.
In the LabVIEW project, there was a part responsible for sending tags values (double values bundled together with tags names and converted to string) over TCP socket to another PC running C# application (TCP Client) which was receiving array of bytes and converting it to double value.

[LabVIEW TCP Server Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fc5d.png)

And part of the code of TCP Client running on another PC.

```
TcpClient                   _client;
NetworkStream               _stream = null;
byte[]                      _data = new byte[8192];

{...}
try
{
    _client     = new TcpClient(properties.IpAddress, properties.Port);
}
{...}
    try
    {
        _stream     = _client.GetStream();
{...}
        int NumBytesInRecvBuffer = _stream.Read(_data, 0, 8192);

{...}
            if(_data[3] == paramCount)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < paramCount; i++)
                {
                    double Value = MakeDouble(_data, 4+(i*8));
                    fmacsParams[i].NumericalValue = Value;
                }
            }
    }
```

`MakeDouble()` function in TCP Client.

```
private unsafe double MakeDouble(byte[] data, int StartIndex)
{
    double result;
    byte* b = (byte*)&result;
    b[0] = data[StartIndex + 7];
    b[1] = data[StartIndex + 6];
    b[2] = data[StartIndex + 5];
    b[3] = data[StartIndex + 4];
    b[4] = data[StartIndex + 3];
    b[5] = data[StartIndex + 2];
    b[6] = data[StartIndex + 1];
    b[7] = data[StartIndex + 0];
    return(result);         
}
```

I managed to develop a simple application in C#, which is a TCP listener and reading the tags values from WinCC Runtime as Object

```
 object ft107Flow = oType.InvokeMember("GetValue", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, wincc, new object[] { "FT107_Flow" });
```

Then it is converted to double and to byte array. Finally all the bytes in the array are swapped with function SwapBytes() and put to data array so it can be sent as byte array over TCP.

```
{...}
const int paramCount = 30;
double[] WinCC_Tags = new double[paramCount];

WinCC_Tags[0] = Convert.ToDouble(ft107Flow);
{...}
byte[] data = new byte[4 + paramCount * 8];
Array.Clear(data, 0, data.Length);

byte[] UnswappedByte;
byte[] SwappedByte;

data[3] = paramCount;

for (int i = 0; i < paramCount; i++)
{
     int j;

     UnswappedByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(WinCC_Tags[i]);
     SwappedByte = SwapBytes(UnswappedByte, 0);

     j = (4 + i * 8);

     data[j] = SwappedByte[0];
     data[j + 1] = SwappedByte[1];
     data[j + 2] = SwappedByte[2];
     data[j + 3] = SwappedByte[3];
     data[j + 4] = SwappedByte[4];
     data[j + 5] = SwappedByte[5];
     data[j + 6] = SwappedByte[6];
     data[j + 7] = SwappedByte[7];
}
```

The problem I'm facing at the moment is these values received by client are not the same. It seems like the precision is lost because of this double or even triple conversion (object -> double, double->byte array; byte array -> double).

For example, in WinCC Runtime the tag value reads 15.3. When it is converted to double, it equals `15.300000190734863`. Then the `data[12..19] = {0x40, 0x2e, 0x99, 0x99, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}`.

The data received by client looks as follows:

`_data[12..19] = {0x40, 0x2e, 0x99, 0x99, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}`

`Value = 15.001172065734863`

It looks like the same data (byte array) are received by client, however the value after conversion does not equal to the value in WinCC Runtime.

Could you please confirm if there is a way of modifying the TCP Listener side so the TCP Client would receive the right data after conversion using MakeDouble() function and without touching TCP Client code (not allowed to modify it).

Comment: Simple :             byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x40, 0x2e, 0x99, 0x99, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            double number = BitConverter.ToDouble(data.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);  I get 15.300.

Comment: His make `MakeDouble()` function is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Instead of swapping bytes yourself I recommend you use
[this](https://github.com/jamesqo/Be.IO) package. It's a BigEdian BinaryReader/Writer

You could use it like this

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (BeBinaryReader BeReader = new BeBinaryReader(stream))
{
    stream.Position = 3;
    if(BeReader.ReadByte() == paramCount)
    for (int i = 0; i < paramCount; i++)
    {
       double Value = BeReader.ReadDouble();
       fmacsParams[i].NumericalValue = Value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The thing is I am not allowed to modify TCP Client code.

Comment: But for reading and writing your data Server side you could use the BigEdian BinaryReader/Writer

Comment: Is there any way to prove that what is inside the function MakeDouble(), converts the byte array to double in such a way that it looses the precision and as a result it returns slightly different value?

Comment: `byte[] value = BitConverter.GetBytes((double)15.300000190734863);
Array.Reverse(value);
Console.WriteLine(MakeDouble(value,0));`

Gives me 15.300000190734863 So it seems to work

Comment: That's interesting. Same piece of code gives me 15.0011720657349

Comment: Any idea why we have two different results running the same code? Am I missing something in my code or project settings or operating system settings?

Comment: Did you copy the piece of testing code into an empty project or in your current project ?

Comment: I copied that to current project and I also created an empty project for testing it and both are giving the same result...

Comment: What version of .net and Visual studio are you using

Comment: Visrtual Machine Windows 7 x64
Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
.NET Version 4.5.51209 SP1Rel

Host Machine Windows 7 x64
Visual Studio 2008 Version 9.0.21022.8 RTM
.NET Version 3.5 SP1

Application tested in both and both are giving the same result...

Comment: The only difference I have is a declaration of MakeDouble()

'private static unsafe double MakeDouble(byte[] data, int StartIndex)'

So it has static declaration, otherwise it gives me an error during compilation.

Comment: This is amazing... I created a new project in the same software (VS 2010) on another laptop and that testing code gives me same result as you had (15.300000190734863). How is that possible that same piece of code compiled in the same development software on two different machines gives two different results?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with how C# handles unsafe code and pointers, but if I were answering this from a C perspective, it looks like the 6th byte is being overwritten by something.

The difference between 15.300000190734863 and 15.0011720657349 is 
{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x99, **0x99**, 0x2e, 0x40} and {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa0, 0x99, **0x00**, 0x2e, 0x40}.

Try the following code

```
    private double MakeDouble(byte[] data, int StartIndex)
    {
        double result;
        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        b[0] = data[StartIndex + 7];
        b[1] = data[StartIndex + 6];
        b[2] = data[StartIndex + 5];
        b[3] = data[StartIndex + 4];
        b[4] = data[StartIndex + 3];
        b[5] = data[StartIndex + 2];
        b[6] = data[StartIndex + 1];
        b[7] = data[StartIndex + 0];
        result = BitConverter.ToDouble(b, 0);
        return (result);
    }
```

Comment: But what actually could cause different result if the same code is complied by the same software on two different PC's?

Comment: Speaking generically (not C# specifically), having different compiler or CLR versions and/or settings can result in different outputs as the systems can attempt to optimize it differently. In C code, optimizers can cause your code to perform unpredictably if it doesn't adhere to proper coding standards, even though when compiled in an unoptimized manner it will perform as expected; I only mention this as an example. 2 questions: 
a) have you tried running the above code?
b) have you tried building on one machine and running the build on the other?